# Display child above all other elements

Tags: html, css

does anyone know how I can center the white circle into to middle of the blue circle and set the white circle above all other elements? I tried with relative and absolute positioning and with the z-index but I couldnt get it to work. I'm kinda a noob in CSS

```css
.start-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 20% 65% 15%;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "startpage" "footer";
}

.header {}

.header-shape {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(0 60%, 100% 40%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.profile-shape {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7vw;
  left: 65vw;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60));
}

.profile-picture {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -50% 0 0 -50%;
}

.startpage {}

.footer {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="start-container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="profile-shape">
      <div class="profile-picture"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-shape"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="startpage"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your shape a `z-index`, it will put it on top.  Make it `flex` with `justify-content` and `align-items` center and that will centre your profile (after removing the absolute positioning):

```css
.start-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 20% 65% 15%;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "startpage" "footer";
}

.header {}

.header-shape {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(0 60%, 100% 40%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.profile-shape {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7vw;
  left: 65vw;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60));
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.profile-picture {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.startpage {}

.footer {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="start-container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="profile-shape">
      <div class="profile-picture"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-shape"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="startpage"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Per comment, if you want blue circle (changed to red in example below) below and white above, you would need to have an extra object otherwise the white circle will always be on the same stacking context as it's parent:

```css
.start-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 20% 65% 15%;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "startpage" "footer";
}

.header {}

.header-shape {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(0 60%, 100% 40%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.profile-placement {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7vw;
  left: 65vw;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
}

.profile-placement--shape {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60));
}

.profile-placement--picture {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.profile-picture {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.startpage {}

.footer {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="start-container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="profile-placement profile-placement--shape">
    </div>
    <div class="profile-placement profile-placement--picture">
      <div class="profile-picture"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="header-shape"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="startpage"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! I really messed up with the units so the circle should be half under the blue shape. If I use the index solution from you, the circle is on top of the blue shape and the shadow is visible. Would there be a way to put the blue circle under the blue shape and the white circle above?

Comment: Ah right, if you wanted that then all three shapes would need to be on the same level - I'll see if I can do something, give me 5

Comment: Yes! That did it, thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

Just adjust the margin with the remaining height and width on the `profile-picture` class.

The remaining size is 10% height and 10% weight. So there will be +5%(-45%) on the left margin and +5%(-45%) on the top margin. It will make the circle center

```css
.start-container{
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 20% 65% 15%;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header"
        "startpage"
        "footer"
    ;
}

.header{
}

.header-shape{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    clip-path: polygon(0 60%, 100% 40%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.profile-shape{
    position: absolute;
    top: 7vw;
    left: 65vw;
    width: 10vw;
    height: 10vw;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.60));
}

.profile-picture{
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -45% 0 0 -45%;
}

.startpage{
}

.footer{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="start-container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="profile-shape">
                <div class="profile-picture"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="header-shape"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="startpage"></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This centered the circle perfectly :)

Comment: @Daniel I'm glad. If this answer solves your question, may be you can mark it as the solution!. TY.